# Review mode, attention check: how do I see other votes to close?

Tags: support, close-reasons, duplicate-questions, review

Sequence of events:

- I review votes to close.
- I see a question. It looks fine. Why is it here?
- I press "Close" to see if there's a proposed 'exact duplicate' in other close votes.
- "We were checking if you're paying attention!". Well, OK.

The question: is there an easy way to see other votes to close, with their reasons?

Of course, I could open the question in another tab and see the close votes there, but probably there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are reviewing close votes, the close reasons others have chosen are shown in the review menu:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Given the "We were checking if you're paying attention!" part of the flow you described, this was an audit rather than an actual "this question needs to be closed"

Given your timing and the review queue [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/29657) was the [audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info).

There are issues with audits that are occasionally brought up on MSO such as one that seems to be similar to your issue:

- [Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote)